# Capture mouse position only from QWidget and NOT from QMainWindow PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm currently developing an app with PyQt5 where I need to get the coordinates from the pointer.

I'm using a QMainWindow with a StatusBar and a Menu along with my central widget being a QWidget where I paint a background.

My problem is that the Menu is adding 23 pixels from the top of the window which are causing problems when I'm getting the mouse position. Is there a way for me to ignore every other mouse position that is not from the drawing? I'd like it so t it begins 0,0 as the top left of the drawing and ends on the bottom right,

I've attached an image of how it is a problem. Where the mouse is on the same position (first square on top left) but after I convert it to the coordinates it shows a different one.

The problem itself

[image]

I'm not sure if I made myself clear, so in the end **how can I ignore the mouse position on anything except from the QWidget?**

**Edit:**

Here's the code:

project.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, qApp, QDialog, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QInputDialog, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QFont, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF

from Punto import Punto

coordinates = []
mask = []
initial = []
final = []

class Settings():

    WIDTH = 25
    HEIGHT = 25
    NUM_BLOCKS_X = 15
    NUM_BLOCKS_Y = 15

    type = ["Wall", "Land", "Water", "Sand", "Forest", "Swamp", "Snow"]
    flags = Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.buildMenu()
        self.setWindowTitle("Labyrinth")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))

        self.openFile()

        self.grid = Grid()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.grid)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.centralWidget().setMouseTracking(True)

        self.resize((Settings.WIDTH*Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X)+1, (Settings.HEIGHT*Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y)+45)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())

    def buildMenu(self):

        exitAct = QAction('&Exit', self)        
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        openAct = QAction('&Open', self)        
        openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAct.setStatusTip('Open a new file')
        openAct.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        setInitial = QAction('&Initial point', self)
        setInitial.setShortcut('Ctrl+I')
        setInitial.setStatusTip("Set the initial point in the labyrinth")
        setInitial.triggered.connect(self.setInitial)

        setFinal = QAction('&Final point', self)
        setFinal.setShortcut('Ctrl+F')
        setFinal.setStatusTip("Set the final point in the labyrinth")
        setFinal.triggered.connect(self.setFinal)

        menubar = self.menuBar()

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        setMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Set...')

        fileMenu.addAction(openAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)
        setMenu.addAction(setInitial)
        setMenu.addAction(setFinal)

    def setInitial(self, coords):
        global initial
        initial = coords
        self.centralWidget().update()

    def setFinal(self, coords):
        global final
        final = coords
        self.centralWidget().update()

    def openFile(self):
        filename = "laberinto.txt"
        archivo = open(filename, "r")

        global coordinates

        puntos = []
        for linea in archivo:
            for x in (linea.strip().split(",")):
                puntos.append(Punto(x))
            coordinates.append(list(puntos))
            puntos.clear()

        coordinates = list(zip(*coordinates))


        Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X = len(coordinates)
        Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y = len(coordinates[0])

        temp = [0] * Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y

        for x in coordinates:
            mask.append([1] * len(coordinates))


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):    
        x = e.x()
        y = e.y()

        self.coordX = (x-(x%Settings.WIDTH))/Settings.WIDTH
        self.coordY = (y-(y%Settings.HEIGHT))/Settings.HEIGHT

        if self.coordX == Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X:
            self.coordX = Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X-1

        if self.coordY == Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y:
            self.coordY = Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y-1

        text = "[{0}, {1}] - {2}".format(int(self.coordX), int(self.coordY), 
            Settings.type[coordinates[int(self.coordX)][int(self.coordY)].type])
        self.statusBar().showMessage(text)


class Grid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        self.drawBackground(event, painter)
        painter.end()

    def getColor(self, x, y):
            type = int(coordinates[x][y].type)
            if int(type) == 0:
                return QColor(128, 128, 128)
            if int(type) == 1:
                return QColor(255, 153, 51)
            if int(type) == 2:
                return QColor(51, 153, 255)
            if int(type) == 3:
                 return QColor(255, 255, 102)
            if int(type) == 4:
                return QColor(0, 153, 0)
            if int(type) == 5:
                return QColor(25, 0, 51)
            if int(type) == 6:
                return QColor(255, 204, 204)

    def drawBackground(self, event, painter):

        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        for x in range (0, Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X+1):
            painter.drawLine(0, x*Settings.WIDTH, Settings.WIDTH*Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X, x*Settings.WIDTH)
        for x in range (0, Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y+1):
            painter.drawLine(x*Settings.HEIGHT, 0, x*Settings.HEIGHT, Settings.HEIGHT*Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y)

        for x in range (0, Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X):
            for y in range (0, Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y):
                if mask[x][y] == 1:
                    painter.setBrush(self.getColor(x, y))
                    painter.drawRect((x*Settings.HEIGHT),(y*Settings.WIDTH), Settings.WIDTH, Settings.HEIGHT)
                    if coordinates[x][y].visited :
                        margin = [int(Settings.HEIGHT*3/4), int(Settings.WIDTH*3/4)]
                        painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255))
                        painter.drawRect(
                            (x*Settings.HEIGHT)+int(margin[0]/2),
                            (y*Settings.WIDTH)+int(margin[0]/2),
                            Settings.WIDTH-margin[1],
                            Settings.HEIGHT-margin[1])
        if initial:
            painter.drawText(QPointF(10+initial[0]*Settings.WIDTH, 20+initial[1]*Settings.HEIGHT), "I")
        if final:
            painter.drawText(QPointF(10+final[0]*Settings.WIDTH, 20+final[1]*Settings.HEIGHT), "F")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    program = Main()
    program.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Punto.py

```
class Punto:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = int(type)
        self.visited = 0

    def visit(self):
        if self.visited==0:
            self.visited = 1
            return 1
```

And the file that the program is opening (laberinto.txt):

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Just did! Thanks for the advice

Comment: @BrandonB Have you solved this? If so, please post the solution as an answer

Comment: @Kathir never solved it. I discarded the top menu.